# QGIS Graphic modeler: Printing a number in a QGIS Print Layout on a specific label Item

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

So far I am trying to create script to add some "supplement" numbers to a lot of lay-outs. This because we want the editing of the lay-outs to be a less as possible.

The Layout name is different each time, the structure and therefore the Item ID's are the same. With around 60 plans editing one by one is kind of hassle even though
**It is actually one specific called the Item called "Bijlage NR" which is a label.** .

So to circumvent this I was trying to see ***if I can build a script/model in the QGIS model builder to just choose the lay-out type choose a number from 1-100 and the it will print that number in that item on my layout.***

The thing is while I can see an option "print" a layout item of a layout in the model builder and there is a option to put a number in, **I do not see an option to kind off express that number in that Item ID.**

**So how do I do this?**

---

Also Bonus:

Currently I can theoretically make this a batch process to edit multiple layers at the same time the annoying thing is, I will also need to select the layout item id "Bijlage NR" each time. As you can guess this is kind of annoying if you have over more than 30 Layouts. If someone can tell me how to refine this QGIS graphic modeler to not have me to select that Item Id in each row of the batch and no I do not mean by expression or anything like that. Just a way to to eliminate that parameter al together.

Comment: Okay, this seems rather complex. Right now I have about four ideas, what you're trying to achieve, and probably all are wrong. Can you try to elaborate?

Comment: I have updated my question Erik with some extra details.

Comment: Let me see if I got this right: You want to create a model which allows you to choose a number, them selects the approriate template for this number and prints the number into the template?

Comment: I select the template/layout/to exporting map (you get the idea) and then it puts the number I selected in a specific label called "Bijlage nr".

Comment: And the layout selection is part of the model. Possible stupid question: Why don't you hardcode the number into the layout? Or is the number not connected to your layout selection? If so, how do you know which "Bijlage nr" you have (aka, what is the source of this number)?

Comment: The source of the number is actually unknown by us this for the client to decide which number goes on each layout. You see all these Layouts are gonna be exported as Pa NG or PDF to be used in a report (pasted into Word). I would hardcode the "Bijlage nr" aka giving each layout a solid number..if it were not for the fact not all plans would be used. In one report Layout 1 has supplement number number 1 but in another report it has number 4. Report 1 has 30 plans report 2 has 20 plans. This what the script is for so that the client can decide.